# Html Rowspan Put on the top

Tags: html, css, html-table

I just want to ask if how I can put the `<td>` on the top since I used a rowspan on the `<td>`. Please see sample below.

This is my code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2">
    <div>January</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowsl">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2">January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I want to have it this way like picture:

[image]

Comment: `vertical-align:top`?

Comment: You may want to upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got multiple solutions.

My main suggestion will be to remove all `rowspan`s and the multiple `tr`s.
See the code I changed into comment in the snippet below:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><!-- rowspan="2"-->
      <div>January</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
  <!--/tr>
  <tr class="rowsl"-->
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><!-- rowspan="2"-->January</td>
  <!--/tr>
  <tr-->
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

From the snippet above, if you ever need to add lines in the `td`, you can add `div`s like you did for the month, and maybe stylize it a little, like that:

```css
td div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/* Or use the one below if you don't want the first column to be stylized

td:not(:first-child) div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

*/
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>January</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>February</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>$80</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, you can do the following, keep the `rowspan` and add the empty `td`s that will make your table structure consistent:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <!-- Do the following -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>January</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can move all `rowspan` `td` in one `tr`

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div>January</div>
      <div>test</div>
      <div>test</div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top">February</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top">$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowsl">
    
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">January</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my answer is what you are looking for:

```html
<table border ="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <tr >
    <td  rowspan="2" >
    <div>January</div><div>test</div><div>test</div>
    </td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="rowsl">
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2">January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is putting it in the same row, but then you will have the same height:

```
  <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
            <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td rowspan="2">
             <div>January</div>
             <div>test</div>
             <div>test</div>
            </td> 
            <td rowspan="2" >February</td>
            <td rowspan="2" >$80</td>
         </tr>

          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">January</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
         </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also write as below code,

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2" >
    <div>January</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowsl">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2">January</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```